# Is there a way to catch the react-native redbox error

Tags: react-native

When an redbox error happens, react-native app often stop responding to touches or behave weirdly.
This is much worse than the app crash because a release version won't show a redbox and users don't know what happened and why the app stop responding. They will delete your app if they cannot do anything with it.

You cannot always make sure there is no bug in your app. So when it happens, we should make sure our users could be remind to restart the app or they will fail to use it.

Catching the redbox error of react-native could let you pop a warning modal box and remind the user the app has encountered some error and then wholly quit the app to let the user restart it.

Answer (score 1):

Found this question randomly while searching for something else, but in the hopes that it might help someone, have a look at the newly introduced `componentDidCatch` lifecycle method introduced in React 16 / React Native 0.50

[More info here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidcatch)

This will show a fallback UI for the component tree the boundary encompasses.

Answer (score 1):

A long time passed but this could help someone:

> A react native module that lets you to register a global error handler
>   that can capture fatal/non fatal uncaught exceptions. The module helps
>   prevent abrupt crashing of RN Apps without a graceful message to the
>   user.

https://github.com/master-atul/react-native-exception-handler